# How to break down signal system call prototype in Linux?

Tags: linux, c, signals, system-calls

I am reading "The Linux Programming Interface", where I find signal system call prototype as stated:

```
#include <signal.h>
void ( *signal(int sig, void (*handler)(int)) ) (int);
```

What is signal here is it function-pointer or simple function?

I want to understand the reason behind putting last (int).

How come signal() is returning last desposition of SIGXXXX despite having void return type?

Comment: Dear @Biswapriyo, then how come it is returning last desposition of SIGXXXX despite having void return type?

Comment: See http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/signal.2.html

Comment: @Biswapriyo Michael Kerrisk (maintainer of the Linux man-pages project) wrote on his book  that _The return value of signal() is the previous disposition of the signal. Like the
handler argument, **this is a pointer to a function returning nothing and taking one
integer argument.**_

Comment: This is a question about C grammar, not related to Linux/Unix

Comment: @炸鱼薯条德里克 If you believe this belongs on SO, the next step would be to vote to close as off-topic, belongs on another site, then choose SO. Bare comments don't get the question into the queue, and custom flags are overkill when a queue exists for that purpose. Thank you!

Comment: On stackoverflow: [What's the meaning of this piece of code? void (*signal(int sig, void (*func)(int)))(int);](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3706704/whats-the-meaning-of-this-piece-of-code-void-signalint-sig-void-funcin)

Comment: There's no `signal()` system call in linux (other than as a deprecated entry on legacy platforms), and the `system()` library functions is itself deprecated and **should not be used**, as explained in its manpage, which is also using since a decade or so a much more readable declaration using a typedef.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to read

```
void ( *signal(int sig, void (*handler)(int)) ) (int);
```

is that it declares a function, `signal`, which takes as arguments

- an `int`
- and a pointer to a function which itself takes an `int` and doesn’t return anything

and returns a pointer to a function which takes an `int` and doesn’t return anything.

The extra brackets correspond to the returned function pointer.

There’s a detailed explanation [on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9501054/4500798). Unfortunately [cdecl.org](https://cdecl.org/) doesn’t work on this declaration (because `cdecl` doesn’t either).